# Restarting forever (node) if script stops

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, ubuntu, forever

I am running a node.js script on aws ubuntu with forever. But sometimes script will error and it STOP running. Is there way that scripts restarts if stops ?

Comment: Try with using pm2 runtime [click here](https://www.npmjs.com/package/pm2)

Comment: Thanks . What would be for PM2 command to restart script by itself if script stops due to xyz reason.

Comment: 'pm2 start app.js --exp-backoff-restart-delay=100'. The more you will find here: [Restart Strategies](https://pm2.io/doc/en/runtime/features/restart-strategies/)

Comment: Thanks @MuhammadOvaisHanif . I got it installed , getting following 2 warnings. No errors dont think its a big deal. Your thoughts ? ```npm WARN optional Skipping failed optional dependency /pm2/chokidar/fsevents:
npm WARN notsup Not compatible with your operating system or architecture: fsevents@1.2.9
```

Comment: Loving PM2 btw... Its sexy !!